# Extjs 4 MessageBox prompt mandatory

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there any way to make the input mandatory on a prompt messagebox in extjs 4, like add an allowBlank config to the textarea...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ext.MessageBox unfortunately does not support controlling the close-behavior based on the return value of the login handler (at least in Ext 4.0.2a the return value is not evaluated at all).

As a workaround you can just re-open another MessageBox in your callback handler with the same (or updated) config.

```
Ext.Msg.prompt('Name', 'Please enter your name:', function(btn, text, cfg) {
    if(btn == 'ok' && Ext.isEmpty(text)) {
        var newMsg = '<span style="color:red">Please enter your name:</span>';
        Ext.Msg.show(Ext.apply({}, { msg: newMsg }, cfg));
    }
});
```

In some cases the user could experience a slight flickering. In my tests, however, it was not noticeable at all. 
If the user has dragged the MessageBox to a different position it will recenter again.

Answer (score 3):

By mandatory do you simply mean force the user to select one of the available buttons?

If so, you can use

```
'closable: false'
```

to prevent the user closing the box without clicking on a button.

Comment: I want to make the input mandatory, he can close the messagebox if he wants.

Comment: I'm not sure there is that functionality directly with 'prompt', but according to the documentation you can specify a callback function on prompt which will take the text entered as a parameter. One options would be to return false from that handler or re-show the same box if that value was empty.

Comment: thanks for the answer i was thinking of something like that, and aparently this is the only way i can do it

Answer (score 0):

I created custom function for set prompt input required with prompt window as argument

```
setPromptRequired: function(promptWin) {
        const field = promptWin.down('textfield');
        const button = promptWin.down('#ok');
        button.disable();
        field.on({
            change: function(item, value) {
                if(value && value.trim() !== '') {
                    button.enable();
                } else {
                    button.disable();
                }
            }
        });

          promptWin.on({
            beforehide: function(){
                button.enable();
                field.resumeEvent('change');
            },
            beforeclose: function(){
                button.enable();
                field.resumeEvent('change');
            }
        });
    }
```